# Load Excel file into numpy 2D array

Tags: python, excel, numpy

Is there an easier way to load an excel file directly into a Numpy array?

I have looked at the `numpy.genfromtxt` autoloading function from numpy documentation but it doesn't load excel files directly.

```
array = np.genfromtxt("Stats.xlsx")
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
Line #3 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
Line #5 (got 5 columns instead of 1)
......
```

Right now I am using using `openpyxl.reader.excel` to read the excel file and then append to numpy 2D arrays. This seems to be inefficient. 
Ideally I would like to have to excel file directly loaded to numpy 2D array.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Honestly, if you're working with heterogeneous data (as spreadsheets are likely to contain) using a [`pandas.DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) is a better choice than using `numpy` directly.

While `pandas` is in some sense just a wrapper around numpy, it handles heterogeneous data very very nicely. (As well as a ton of other things... For "spreadsheet-like" data, it's the gold standard in the python world.)

If you decide to go that route, just use [`pandas.read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.excel.read_excel.html).

Comment: I would just add that to convert a data frame to a Numpy 2D array you can just use np.asarray(your_data_frame_here).

Comment: No, Sir. Pandas is not necessarily better. Pandas is incredibly slow--especially when loading even moderately large data files.

Comment: I agree, I really do not want to be forced into dealing with Pandas dataframes.  It just unnecessary baggage and complication and one more unnecessary depency, for what should be simple numerical data.   How about a simple direct solution without pandas please.

Comment: @AnthonyGatlin then what do you suggest as an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

We can do it using **xlrd** library. We don't need to import entire pandas.

Here is below utility function, taken from [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75819343/8630792)

```py
def read_excel(excel_path, sheet_no = 0):
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(excel_path)
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(sheet_no)
    return numpy.array([list(map(lambda x : x.value, sheet.row(i))) for i in range(sheet.nrows)])
```

Hope this helps other who want to avoid pandas to read excel.

**For me this alternative was 1 second slower than `pandas.read_excel(...).to_numpy()` for excel with 14k records**