# extract excel columns into python array

Tags: python, arrays, excel

I want to extract excel columns (NOT rows) into python arrays of array. It has to be arrays, not dictionaries.

The excel file looks like this:

```
     A    B    C
1   123  534  576
2   456  745  345
3   234  765  285
```

I want to bring this into python in the following format:

```
[[123,534,576],[456,745,345],[234,765,285]]
```

How would I do this? Thank you

Comment: Look into the [```xlrd```](http://www.python-excel.org/) package

Comment: @wnnmaw I did and I also looked at numpy, but I don't know how to do columns. I am able to do only rows

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load Excel file into numpy 2D array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052991/load-excel-file-into-numpy-2d-array)

Comment: @user1681664, what have you tried with ```xlrd``` to pull the columns?

Comment: @user1681664 This [library](https://github.com/camyoung1234/spreadsheet) may interest you.

Comment: Surely columns would be: `[[123, 456, 234], [534, 745, 765], [576, 345, 285]]` - either way, using `xlrd` it's `row_values` or `col_values` - the documentation is fairly simple to follow...

Comment: Terminology issue: you say "arrays of array", but there are several things people call `arrays` when Python's involved.  The standard library has a type called `array`; the popular `numpy` library has an `ndarray` type, which spells itself "array" sometimes; and beginners sometimes call a Python `list` an array.  It looks like you want a list of lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
import csv
cr = csv.reader(open("temp.csv","rb"))
arr = range(100)  # adjust to needed
x = 0
for row in cr:    
    arr[x] = row
    x += 1

print(arr[:22])  # adjust to needed
```

Answer (score 13):

#### Here's a yet simpler approach:

```
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook('your.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_name('example')
data = [[sheet.cell_value(r, c) for c in range(sheet.ncols)] for r in range(sheet.nrows)]
# Profit !
print(data)
```

Comment: It'd be great if you can also add how to retrieve a particular cell value from `data`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're following the above comments and look into the xlrd package, can you try this and see if it works?

(based on what I found here: [http://www.youlikeprogramming.com/2012/03/examples-reading-excel-xls-documents-using-pythons-xlrd/](https://web.archive.org/web/20121014160149/http://www.youlikeprogramming.com/2012/03/examples-reading-excel-xls-documents-using-pythons-xlrd/))

```
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('my_workbook.xls')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
num_rows = worksheet.nrows - 1
curr_row = 0

#creates an array to store all the rows
row_array = []

while curr_row < num_rows:
    row = worksheet.row(curr_row)
    row_array += row
    curr_row += 1

print(row_array)
```

Comment: Does it work for Excel 2010 also? File type is "xlsx" or "xlsm"?

Comment: Good question. Not sure to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

Use xlrd to load the data *row-wise*, then use zip to transpose it.

```
>>> 
>>> a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> zip(*a)
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
>>>
```

Use xlrd to load the data *row-wise*, use it to create a numpy array, then transpose it.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> z = numpy.array(a)
>>> z
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
>>> z.transpose()
array([[1, 4, 7],
       [2, 5, 8],
       [3, 6, 9]])
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
array = []
with open(* insert file directory here*) as fin:
     reader = csv.reader(fin)
     rows = [row for row in reader]
     for row in rows:
        j = 0
        arr = []
        for i = 0 < 3:
          arr[i] = row[i]
        array[j] = arr
        j = j + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

csv_rows = csv.reader(open("temp.csv","r"))
result_array = []
for row_index, row in enumerate(csv_rows):   
    if row_index != 0: #to neglect column names row
        result_array.append(row)
print(result_array)
```

Comment: Hi Tushar. Could you please add an explanation to all your answers even if it is only a brief one. Also, there are already a lot of answers for this question. Why do we need another one? There is no  explanation of why this solution should be considered over the others. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.